# How to guarantee script loading in Google Chrome : defer doesn't seem enough

Tags: javascript, dom-events, kineticjs

I'm reading this tut series on Google Chrome here  http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-text-tutorial/ by clicking next I would go on next page http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-spline-tutorial/

Problem is that rather often nothing draws : I have to create a new tab and copy and paste the url instead of clicking next page.

So it seems that in Google Chrome script like kinetic js library used here cannot load reliably even with defer attribute used in the page doesn't seem enough.

How could one fix this?

Comment: I'm not having problems "nexting" through the tutorials using ChromeV29 on win7.

Comment: does your console log shows any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually is a bug in chrome 29, should be resolved in chrome 30.

As a temporary work-around you can enable #disable-accelerated-2d-canvas in chrome://flags

Comment: Any link to the bug report?